# How to Displaying DOJO Autocompleter value with ajax

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, dojo

I'm trying to do an ajax retrieval of a hashmap of info using the dojo autocompleter, but nothing seems to be showing on the dropdown menu. please help

My JSP Code :

```
 <sx:head/>
 .......
 <s:url id="companyList" action="AjaxAutoCompleteCompanyPOCAction" />
 <sx:autocompleter name="company" href="%{companyList}"  size="24" loadOnTextChange="true"  preload="false" loadMinimumCount="1" showDownArrow="false" autoComplete="false" searchType="substring" key="rental.company"/>
```

my Struts.XML:

```
  <action name="AjaxAutoCompleteCompanyPOCAction" class="com.kodi.action.jobs.AjaxAutoCompleteCompanyPOCAction" method="retrieveListOfCompany" >
       <result type="json">
           <param name="root">json</param>
       </result>
    </action>
```

my Action

```
 public String retrieveListOfCompany(){
    //if(KodiUtil.isMatch(getCompany())){ // validate special char
        setJson(new HashMap<String, String>()); // create a JSON hashmap
         if(company != null && company.length() > 0) { // check if string is empty
              List<CompanyEntity> companylist = manager.retrieveCompanyName(getCompany());  // retrieve the companies name
              for (CompanyEntity companies : companylist){
                 getJson().put(companies.getCompany_name(),""+companies.getCompany_id());
              }

         }
    return "SUCCESS";

}
```

As of now, the code does call retrieveListOfCompany() in my Action class, n get the data but it doesn't display on the JSP page.. please help..
I'm getting this error,

```
No result defined for action com.kodi.action.jobs.AjaxAutoCompleteCompanyPOCAction and result SUCCESS
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:375)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
```

but when i set my struts.xml to

```
<result name="SUCCESS" type="json">
           <param name="root">json</param>
       </result>
```

I get this =(

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:157)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
```

I'm using struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar for this

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use dojo plugin?

Comment: Not really.. seems easiler tho but it just cant work =(

Comment: Actually I won't mind helping you, but you asked 4 questions already and accepted none of them.

Comment: oh.. lol my apology..  didn't understood wat u were toking about previously lol.., kinda new to this forumn so..  >.>

Accepted them =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo plugin is deprecated from Struts2, but there is JQuery plugin http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/ and showcase http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out wat was wrong with my app,

the error i got is becoz of the incompatibility of the jsonplugin with my dojo and struts core..

so if anybody is having the same issue, just downgrade ur jar files to a more compatible version

Currently i'm using

struts2-json-plugin-2.2.1

struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1

struts2-core-2.2.1.1

Hope this helps